# Using a Tkinter Widget from Lower Down in the Program

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, variables, tkinter

So I'm trying to make this tkinter GUI in which you can add or search for a customer (the customer is stored in a SQlite database). Problem is, I can't see a way of making the def for when the add customer button is pressed, for as far as I know, I would need to use the names of the variables from lower down in the program where the widgets are created. I could switch the order of the functions around, but then the widgets would be calling functions that have not already been created. Can someone help fix this probem? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code:

```
    from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.minsize(400,420)
app.title("Gatecode Manager")
app.resizable(False, False)

def add():
    first = createWindow().firstAdd.get()
    last = createWindow().firstAdd.get()
    phone = createWindow().numberAdd.get()


def createWindow():
    Label(text="Welcome to Gatecode Manager", font=("bold", 17)).grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=30, sticky=N)

    Label(text="Search for a Customer").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
    Label(text="First Name:").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
    firstSearch = Entry().grid(row=3, column=0, padx=30)
    Label(text="Last Name:").grid(row=4, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
    lastSearch = Entry().grid(row=5, column=0, padx=30)

    Label(text="Add Customer to System").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
    Label(text="First Name:").grid(row=2, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
    firstAdd = Entry().grid(row=3, column=1, padx=30)
    Label(text="Last Name:").grid(row=4, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
    lastAdd = Entry().grid(row=5, column=1, padx=30)
    Label(text="Phone Number:").grid(row=6, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
    numberAdd = Entry().grid(row=7, column=1, padx=30)
    add = Button(text="Add", command="null").grid(padx=30, pady=10, column=1)

    app.mainloop()

createWindow()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it difficult to understand exactly how you want this program to function. Is the `add` button supposed to call the function `add()` which then calls `createWindow()`?

I'm guessing a little here but what about:

1) Don't create the GUI in a function. A function will keep the variables in the scope of the functioin.

2) Use StringVar() to access entries. Since you don't save the identity of your entries it becomes impossible to interrogate them.

Example:

```
from tkinter import *

app = Tk()
app.minsize(400,420)
app.title("Gatecode Manager")
app.resizable(False, False)

def add():
    first = firstAddVar.get()
    last = firstAddVar.get()
    phone = numberAddVar.get()

Label(text="Welcome to Gatecode Manager", font=("bold", 17)).grid(row=0, 
      columnspan=2, pady=30, sticky=N)
Label(text="Search for a Customer").grid(row=1, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
Label(text="First Name:").grid(row=2, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
firstSearchVar = StringVar()
firstSearch = Entry(textvar=firstSearchVar).grid(row=3, column=0, padx=30)
Label(text="Last Name:").grid(row=4, column=0, padx=30, pady=10)
lastSearchVar  = StringVar()
lastSearch = Entry(textvar=lastSearchVar).grid(row=5, column=0, padx=30)

Label(text="Add Customer to System").grid(row=1, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
Label(text="First Name:").grid(row=2, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
firstAddVar = StringVar()
firstAdd = Entry(textvariable=firstAddVar).grid(row=3, column=1, padx=30)
Label(text="Last Name:").grid(row=4, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
lastAddVar = StringVar()
lastAdd = Entry(textvariable=lastAddVar).grid(row=5, column=1, padx=30)
Label(text="Phone Number:").grid(row=6, column=1, padx=30, pady=10)
numberAddVar = StringVar()
numberAdd = Entry(textvariable=numberAddVar).grid(row=7, column=1, padx=30)
add = Button(text="Add", command=add).grid(padx=30, pady=10, column=1)

app.mainloop()
```

When your GUIs become more complex you should study OOP.